# What is the mur incense

Tags: halacha, animals, smell

How can I find the mur incense?

From
[Harav 297.3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/297/3.htm)

> ...
>   ומכל מקום טוב להניח חתיכת מור בתוך מיני ריחות שמברכים עליהם בורא מיני בשמים כדי שיברך ברכת בורא מיני בשמים כהלכתה:

I see that there is a plus in using mur for the besomim after shabos

How can I find what it is
The newest description of it that I found is

[Sidur of the Rav 11.5](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/11.htm)

> וכל שאינו לא מין עץ ולא מין עשב כגון המור והוא מוסק (שקורין פיזו"ם בל"א) היוצא מחטוטרות שבצואר חיה ידוע שמתקבץ שם תחלה כמין דם ואחר כך מתיבש ונעשה ממנו המור מברך על ריחו בורא מיני בשמים ואסור לאכלו וליתנו בתבשיל משום חשש דם ויש מתירין ובעל נפש יחמיר לעצמו בספק של תורה:

But I do not understand what it is saying
I only understand that it is called pizom, and it is somthing that grows in the neck of a known animal but I do not know which one (I heard it is a not kosher animal)

If someone knows what animal it is it will help me try to find the mur

Thank you in advance

Comment: While this doesn't affect your question, you could use anything which is not a plant for Besamim for the same benefit.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please give me some examples

Comment: Sources on subject Comenteris on shemois 30.23 אבן עזרא רמב''ן

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan points out](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=30), many say that the Biblical "myrrh" was an herb. However Rambam and others say it's musk.

> myrrh
>     (Raavad, Kley HaMikdash 1:3; Ramban; Bachya; Septuagint). Mor in Hebrew. Myrrh is a gum resin produced by trees and shrubs of the family Burseracea, most notably Commiphora myrrha, Commiphora abysinica, and Commiphora schimperi. The resin is obtained from Arabia and adjacent Africa, and is taken from the small, prickly gray-barked trees. Pearls of myrrh are brown, red or yellow, with an oily texture, becoming hard and brittle with age. It has a pleasing fragrance, very much like balsam, and a lasting, bitter, aromatic taste, hence the name mor, which signifies bitterness.
>
> According to many authorities, however, the mur here is not myrrh but musk (Saadia; Yad, Kley HaMikdash 1:3; Abarbanel; cf. Radak, Sherashim; Ibn Janach). This is an extract taken from the musk deer (Moschus moschiferus) which lives in Nepal and Tibet (see Ibn Ezra).

If I recall correctly, Malbim says it's also an animal product -- I believe a non-kosher one.

Anyhow, the Shulchan Aruch HaRav was clearly using "mor" as the translation for an animal-derived fragrance. His point is that you can't say any of the plant-fragrance blessings on it (e.g. *borei isvei vesamim*), so you say *borei minei vesamim* -- "all kinds of fragrances" -- which functions as the *shehakol* of fragrances, the broad catch-all.

When it comes to havdala, Sefardic practice is simple enough -- you make whatever blessing is appropriate for the fragrance you have. *Hanoten re'ah tov baPerot* for freshly-ground coffee; *borei atzei vesamim* for roses; and so on. Ashkenazic practice at some point became -- "eh we're afraid people will get confused and not make the right bracha, so just make a *minei* on everything so you're always safe."

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav is then saying if you want to do it extra-right, have some musk on the table so that you're not just respecting Ashkenazic practice of saying *minei vesamim*, you're actually saying the most-specific bracha for this fragrance!

Comment: Original Ramban regarding the מור

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.30.23.1?with=all

Comment: Very interesting statement, esp. last 2 paragraphs. Though, since you contrast Sephardim & Ashkenazim, there's an impression (not yours, I realize) that Ashkenazim became somewhat "lazy".

Comment: @DanF it wasn't laziness. It was developing policies for those with very little education. (Not entirely unlike how the OU doesn't want to confuse Average Joe with OU-D vs OU-DE)

Comment: @Shalom Hmm.. good point. And the Sephardim knew the difference with the brachot better?

Answer (score 2):

The word םור is commonly translated as "myrrh" based on numerous English translations that I have seen such as in Birnbaum & Art Scroll Siddur as wellas Stone Chumash. (I haven't seen another translation.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrrh) describes this as:

> Myrrh /ˈmɜr/ from the Hebrew '"מור"' ("mor") and Arabic مر (mur) is
>   the aromatic resin of a number of small, thorny tree species of the
>   genus Commiphora,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrrh) which is an essential oil termed an oleoresin.
>   Myrrh resin is a natural gum. It has been used throughout history as a
>   perfume, incense and medicine. It can also be ingested by mixing it
>   with wine.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musk)

This is from a plant, not an animal. A Google search revealed that myrrh is widely available in various forms, esp. as an essential oil.

Translating the Siddur Harav:

"Anything that is neither a type of grass or tree such as "mor" which is musk (sorry, I can't translate the parenthetical part), which comes from the hump (nape) of the neck of an animal, it is known that (this sunstance) gathers there (at the neck) first as a from of blood, and then it dries and the "mor" comes from it. You make the blessing *Borei Minei Besamim*. But one is forbidden to eat this or put it in cooking, because there is a possibility that this may be considered blood. There are some that permit it, but it is better to be strict because of a possibility of violating a Biblical prohibition."

Curious, myself, I looked up [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musk) about musk which states:

> Musk is a class of aromatic substances commonly used as base notes in
>   perfumery. They include glandular secretions from animals such as the
>   musk deer, numerous plants emitting similar fragrances, and artificial
>   substances with similar odors.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musk) Musk was a name originally given
>   to a substance with a penetrating odor obtained from a gland of the
>   male musk deer. The substance has been used as a popular perfume
>   fixative since ancient times and is one of the more expensive animal products > in the world.

The Wikipedia article states that musk could come from either the musk deer, which is a kosher animal, or the musk rat (aka muskrat) which is a non-kosher animal.

Well, in terms of obtaining this "mor", it depends on which translation you wish to follow. Both myrrh and musk are available quite easily.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your work, but I still want to know what did the source I brought mean

Comment: See updated edits. The research was quite fascinating.

Comment: Ramban regarding the מור http://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.30.23.1?with=all